# Multiplication of block matrices

Tags: matrices

Let $J_{m \times n}$ be an $m \times n$ matrix of $1$'s (and to abbreviate we write $J_m=J_{m \times m}$) and let $M=\begin{pmatrix} 0_n & J_{n \times m} \\ J_{m \times n} & 0_m \end{pmatrix}$.

I am trying to figure out how to calculate $M^2$. Doing this manually (and always using the fact that multiplying a matrix of size $r \times s$ and one of size $s \times t$ results in a product matrix of size $r \times t$), I would deduce that
$$M^2=\begin{pmatrix} 0_n & J_{n \times m} \\ J_{m \times n} & 0_m \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0_n & J_{n \times m} \\ J_{m \times n} & 0_m \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} J_n^2 & 0_{n \times m} \\ 0_{m \times n} & J_m^2 \end{pmatrix},$$
or so I thought. However, Mathematica (substituting $m=2$, $n=3$ for example) suggests that
$$M^2=\begin{pmatrix} mJ_n & 0_{n \times m} \\ 0_{m \times n} & nJ_m \end{pmatrix},$$
which is probably the correct answer. I can't figure out why the $(2,2)$ entry is actually $J_m^3$ and not $J_m^2$...

Mathematica screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Try it with some friendly block matrices $\begin{bmatrix} 0&2\\2&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0&2\\2&0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 4&0\\0&4\end{bmatrix}$. Maybe double check what you put into Mathematica. These aren't matrices of 1s, but there's no reason it should be different.

Comment: I added the Mathematica screenshot. There are $3$'s instead of $2$'s in the bottom $2\times 2$ part of $M^2$. Maybe I'm just overlooking some detail...

Comment: Oh, $m$ and $n$ are different, but it's not a cube, if the $J$s are matrices of all $1$s, then $J_{m\times n}J_{n\times m} =nJ_{m\times m}$ (compute it more or less directly). It isn't that you have them squared or cubed, but that they are multiplied by a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Well for a matrix where all terms are 1s you have

$$
J_{n,m}J_{m,n} = mJ_{n,n}
$$

Seems like your first derivation omits the factor of n and m.  I think with this you could prove it.

As a side, if you meant that they are unity matrices, then the powers are equivalent so your answers are equivalent.